# Probability with multiple dice rolls

Tags: probability, dice

A friend of mine recently created a game where your movements on the plateau are determined by series of dice throws. The rules are simple: you have exactly $6$ dice that you should throw simultaneously. However, by trading a specific resource (not discussed here), you can choose to throw again any dice you want (except the dice you previously chose to keep). Let's clarify this with an example.

> Consider this: I want $6 \times 6$ (the maximal output).
>
> Throw $1$, output $6, 6, 2, 1, 4, 5 \implies$ I keep the two $6$ and throw again the $4$ other dice.
>
> Throw $2$, output $6, 5, 3, 4 \implies$ I keep the single $6$ and I guess you figured it out.

Now, for the question, I would like to compute the probability of successfully outputting $6$ times $6$ with at most **n** throws. The blunt answer is to considered all the favorable "paths" to my output, for example with $6$ times $6$ in $3$ throws: $0$ first throw, $0$ second throw, $6$ third throw, etc., which is $36$ paths I reckon.

Needless to say, the process of computing such probabilities for a high number of throws is quite the hassle. Obviously we can consider that outputting $6\times6$ in at most $3$ throws is equivalent to doing so in exactly $1$ throw OR in exactly $2$ throw OR in exactly $3$ throw which is convenient because you have an iterative process. However, there is still $21$ unique paths for successfully outputting $6\times6$ in exactly $3$ throws.

Is there a crafty way to compute said probability that I'm not envisioning?

Comment: It's actually quite easy. Consider each dice separately. We want each dice to roll $6$ at least once in $n$ throws. So, for a given dice, the probability of getting a $6$ is $1-\left(\frac56\right)^n$. And, we want each dice to be a $6$, so our final answer is $$\left(1-\left(\frac56\right)^n\right)^6$$

Comment: "Dice" is plural.  the singular is "die".

Comment: @DonThousand Slick.  You should make that an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "**at most**" *n* throws"?

Comment: @trueblueanil You might finish in fewer throws.  For example, you could throw $6$ sixes on the first roll.

Comment: @saulspatz: But you may never finish ? like the only things certain are death and taxes ?

Comment: @trueblueanil If you don't succeed in $n$ rolls, you stop.  In other words, what is the probability that it takes no more than $n$ rolls to get a $6$ with each die?

Comment: @saulspatz: It might better have just read  "...$6$ times $6$ with **n** throws."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making this an answer for completeness.

It's actually quite easy. Consider each die separately. We want each die to roll $6$ at least once in $n$ throws. So, for a given die, the probability of getting a $6$ is $1−\left(\frac56\right)^n$. And, we want each dice to be a $6$, so our final answer is $$\left(1−\left(\frac56\right)^n\right)^6$$

Comment: Thank you for this answser.